# Screen laptop display flickering

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure

This is a problem with a screen of a laptop. It's something related with a broken wires in the junction between the computer and the lid because my webcam, that is on the lid too, sometimes it leave working when I touch on the lid.

Does anyone know what it is?

I recorded a video reporting the problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IipyFT422Hc

At the beginning we can see the image flickering and then when I change the image by changing the windows. In the end, we see a CRT monitor connected to laptop running well.

**EDIT**

The warranty is no longer available.
It's a Insys M761SU, a detailed description can be found here: http://rigon.me/insys_m761su.html

Answer (score 3):

For the best advice, please post your computer brand and model.  I can't tell from the video, but based on the symptoms and the style of the screen's bezel, I'm going to guess it's a Toshiba Satellite, possibly M300 series.  This is a very common problem with certain Toshiba laptops, especially the M300 series.  Mine was an M305D, and two friends with the same issue also have M300s.

If it's under warranty, you should send it in for repair.  However be warned that in my experience with Toshiba (as well as the friend who sent his in), they will try everything to convince you the warranty has been voided somehow (the first excuse they gave me was a scratch on the palmrest, and the second excuse was "We do not and have never repaired screen issues under any warranty", both direct contradictions to both their printed and online warranties).  If you go this route, make sure you only mention the specific issue.  Do not mention anything you think could be the cause or they will assume you opened it.

The reason behind this is Toshiba routinely switches part suppliers to the most inexpensive possible.  One of their preferred LCD cable manufacturers has a terrible track record in regards to product quality and reliability.  These cables frequently get small breaks in the wire near the hinge.

If your computer is no longer under warranty, don't bother sending it in for repair.  They will want at least $200 to replace a cable that likely costs them $20 or less.  That doesn't include labor and shipping.  Your best bet in this case is to try to find a new cable and install it yourself.  [This article](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/image-flickers-disappears-when-move-display-satellite-m305-m305d-laptop/) will help you get started. Fixing it yourself with a good quality cable (rather than the kind Toshiba prefers) will cost less than $100 (a quick search pulls up a few ranging between $40-$60).

If you're wondering about my M305D, it's currently running as a server in my house ([headless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_system) of course).

Comment: The laptop is no longer under warranty.
You probably do not know the brand, it is a Insys M761SU, is a Portuguese brand. You can find a detailed description of the laptop in the link: http://rigon.me/insys_m761su.html

Comment: In that case, I've found a replacement cable at http://infotactil.pt/artigos/detalhes/id/2908 for 15 Euro.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the wires for obvious damage.
- At the place where touching helps, trying to somehow fix it in a way that it's always in a *touched* state.
- Replace the screen as a last option...

Comment: For a flicker, I'd replace the inverter (or LED controller card if this is an all-LED display) before I'd replace the panel itself.  This assuming that it's separate, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing refresh rate from 85Hz to 70Hz help? If not, then I would guess it is the connector that is buggered. ON YOUR OWN RISK open the box up and check all the connectors and then fasten ALL THE SCREWS - that usually helps as well.