# Weird LED laptop screen flickering after replacement

Tags: laptop, display, led

I have a 3 years old Toshiba Satellite L750D. A couple of days ago it's screen started having random noisy horizontal bars on the screen (some noises for 1-2 seconds, then nothing for minutes, then noises again). After I rebooted, the screen backlight died completely. So I called a service where I got informed that LED screens don't have inverters or any other source of backlight problems, other than the backlight itself going out, and that backlight can't be replaced separate from the screen, so I would have to buy a new screen. Last week I went to the service, bought one and had them install it.

Ever since then, when I move the lid at around 90 degrees, or lift the laptop with the lid open at that position, I often (not always) get this annoying flickering (whole screen going black for a split second, sometimes 2-3 times in a row). For first I suspected cable malfunction, but I could also hear a strange, soft electric noise during these blackouts.

Yesterday I took it back to the service. Cables were OK, after a quick look they didn't know what the problem was. It seemed to them like something with the lid switch was going on which clearly wasn't, given that it's a magnetic sensor near the touchpad and has no interaction with the open lid. And now a couple of minutes ago, when I disconnected the charger cable, it went off (with noise) for like 2 seconds, then back on again, so I'm afraid it might even be a motherboard issue.

Any information/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
when I move the lid at around 90 degrees, or lift the laptop with the lid open at that position.

I could also hear a strange, soft electric noise during these blackouts
```

AFAIK, It could be due to **cable/connection problem** only.

You can find the same answer in some other similar questions:

1. [My Laptop Screen keeps flickering](https://superuser.com/questions/130662/my-laptop-screen-keeps-flickering)
2. [Lenovo G530 laptop screen flicker](https://superuser.com/questions/226680/lenovo-g530-laptop-screen-flicker)
3. [Screen laptop display flickering](https://superuser.com/questions/277840/screen-laptop-display-flickering)
4. [Laptop Screen Blackout / Flicker issue; Works fine on External Monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/438982/laptop-screen-blackout-flicker-issue-works-fine-on-external-monitor)

Comment: I can't think of anything else either, but as I wrote above, cables/connections were double checked and they should be okay (at least that's what I've been told by the service staff). I intend to take it back again, but then I'd have to leave it there, and as a university student I couldn't afford any more great expenses nor the time without a computer with finals coming up. Thanks for your answer though. :)